# Stretching for this right hand piano chord: B3 D4 G4 B4

Tags: piano, chords

I've got this G chord in a piece I'm trying to play but stretching for it is difficult. I'm fingering this 1/2/4/5, but it's still quite a stretch. Is this a pretty common shape that I should be striving to stretch for, or if not, what's the most viable alternative to retain the sound but make the chord a little easier to play?

[image: G chord image]

Comment: Try playing 1 &  2 an octave up,  or 4 &  5 am octave down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that this is a very common chord shape, and it would be good to get it under control.  Is the problem your hand size?  Can you reach an octave without too much effort?

The best simplification would be to drop the low B (and finger the remaining notes 1-3-5).  B is the third of the chord, which least needs to be doubled, especially in a lower voice, and extra especially because it's already in the bass.

Comment: No issues reaching an octave, I can even reach a 9th. I'll work on stretching for this. I think it's just my ring finger that doesn't stretch too far from my pinky at this point. Thank you!